# Upgrading mysql connector version to 8.0 from 5.1.42

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, java-11

Will this upgrade work with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ? Because with change in driver i.e com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver throws could not start container error.

```
ERROR [main] 0].tryStart(264) | Could not start container
org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:129)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:259)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:212)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:76)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:210)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:199)
    at com.nexage.nexus.common.BaseNexus_IT.<clinit>(BaseNexus_IT.java:280)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Added below dependency in pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in ds.properties file

```
 datasource.name=coreDS
 datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:18082/core?useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false&profileSQL=true&maxQuerySizeToLog=16384&serverTimezone=America/New_York
 datasource.username=root
 datasource.password=mysql
```

The code which starts the container:

> public static GenericContainer mysqlCore;

```
    mysqlCore = new MySQLImageContainer(testProperties.get("mysql.docker.image").toString())
            .withUsername(testProperties.get("db.username").toString())
            .withPassword(testProperties.get("db.password").toString())
            .withDatabaseName("core");
    mysqlCore.setPortBindings(Arrays.asList(testProperties.get("mysql.core.db.port").toString() + ":3306/tcp"));

    System.out.println(" starting mysql container");
    mysqlCore.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was resolved by upgrading Test container to 1.14.3 along with new mysql driver and mysql connector 8.0 version.